# How to get working directory hash acknowledging all uncommitted changes?

Tags: windows, mercurial

Part of my software build process includes getting the hash of the working directory parent into a C++ string for inclusion in the "version" output. This is done by using `hg identify -i` to get the global revision id, and copying this output into a .h file for inclusion. I do this in a Windows batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims=;=" %%a in ('hg identify -i') do (
  echo const std::string revision^(_T^("%%a"^)^); > rev.h
)
```

Which will output something like this into the file:

```
const std::string revision(_T("3b746fd492c6"));
```

If the working directory has any uncommitted changes, the hash has a `+` appended, making the string `"3b746fd492c6+"`. This allows me to easily check whether the version of software I have built is controlled or not - if the string includes a `+` then the software is not reproducible from the repository.

However, `hg identify` adds a `+` to denote uncommitted changes, but it does not recognised untracked files. If I commit all changes but forget to add that all-important "do stuff" class, `hg identify` will not indicate this.

So my question is: how can I get the required functionality?
How can I simulate `hg identify` recognising new and removed files?

Ideally I would like to not have to use extensions, but will consider them as an option.

---

### Update

Following on from Oben Sonne's suggestion of using a combination of `hg st` and `hg id -r .` I have come up with the following batch file which produces quite a nice result:

```
@echo off
set REPOMODS=
for /F %%a IN ('hg st -n') DO set REPOMODS=+

for /f "tokens=1 delims=;=" %%a in ('hg identify -i -r .') do (
  echo const std::string revision^(_T^("%%a%REPOMODS%"^)^); > rev.h
)
```

`%REPOMODS%` is empty unless there is anything in the output of the `hg st`, in which case it is `+`. I've done a few tests and it seems to work.

Is there another solution which requires less faffing in batch files? Or is this the best I'll get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply checking if the output of `hg st` is empty? If not, add a `+` yourself to the version (if not already given by `hg id`).

**UPDATE:** To prevent the double `+` issue, you could run `hg id -r .`, which never gives you a trailing `+`.

Comment: +1 for removal the trailing `+`, which I couldn't for the life of my figure out (I really should read the manual more). I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't involve me parsing the output too much, tho' - will need to check my batch references for checking for empty output.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it's what led me to the Update to my question (and a working solution). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to my own question is to do something similar to the following, which will perform a test addremove and parse any output. I don't really like it, but offer it as a possible solution in the hope that someone else has a better idea:

```
set ADDREMOVERESULT=
for /F %%a IN ('hg addremove -n') DO set ADDREMOVERESULT=+
if "%ADDREMOVERESULT%"=="+" echo New or Removed Files
```

The issue with this solution is that if there are both modified and new/removed files, the version string could end up with `++`. Not a big problem, but there you go.